# Filtering out different combinations from the same DF and then summarize them in a separate dataframe (tidyverse)

Tags: r, tidyverse, anova

Here's a reprex

```
library(tidyverse)

#first value
diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut, color) %>%
  filter(cut != "Ideal" | color != "E") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  summarize(mean1 = mean(price))

#second value
diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut, color) %>%
  filter(cut != "Premium" | color != "E") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  summarize(mean2 = mean(price))
```

So I'm trying to plot different means against each-other by a specific combinations of values through dplyr's `filter()` function. At the moment the only way I can create these points is by doing the steps above, the problem is, there are 16 points I need to create that way which can make the whole process quite tedious because I'd have to use different pipes with the same functions over and over **BUT** a different combination of values.

Is there a way to make this easier?

If it can help to find the answer, I've created different planned contrasts for two variables in my dataset for a repeated measure design analysis. I then need to look at the effect (means) of every combination and interaction of contrasts.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the most elegant solution, but you can calculate the group means, cross join the result to itself, and then filter out "matching" rows. The `join` column is a dummy column of all 1s used to make the cross join.

```
group_means <- diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut, color) %>%
  summarize(n = n(), mean_price = mean(price)) %>%
  mutate(join = 1)

group_means %>%
  inner_join(group_means, by = 'join') %>%
  filter(cut.x != cut.y | color.x != color.y) %>%
  group_by(cut.x, color.x) %>%
  summarize(weighted.mean(mean_price.y, n.y))

# A tibble: 35 x 3
# Groups:   cut.x [5]
   cut.x color.x `weighted.mean(mean_price.y, n.y)`
   <ord> <ord>                                <dbl>
 1 Fair  D                                    3932.
 2 Fair  E                                    3934.
 3 Fair  F                                    3933.
 4 Fair  G                                    3931.
 5 Fair  H                                    3926.
 6 Fair  I                                    3930.
 7 Fair  J                                    3930.
 8 Good  D                                    3939.
 9 Good  E                                    3942.
10 Good  F                                    3940.
# ... with 25 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function which removes one combination of `cut` and `color` value and calculates the `mean`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

return_mean <- function(p, q) {
  diamonds %>%
    filter(cut != p | color != q) %>%
    summarize(remove_cut = p, 
              remove_color = q, 
              mean = mean(price))
}
```

You can use this function for every combination of `cut` and `color` and combine the results.

```
map_df(unique(diamonds$cut), function(x) 
  map_df(unique(diamonds$color), function(y) return_mean(x, y)))

#  remove_cut remove_color  mean
#   <ord>      <ord>        <dbl>
# 1 Ideal      E            4037.
# 2 Ideal      I            3912.
# 3 Ideal      J            3916.
# 4 Ideal      H            3935.
# 5 Ideal      F            3975.
# 6 Ideal      G            3954.
# 7 Ideal      D            4005.
# 8 Premium    E            3951.
# 9 Premium    I            3878.
#10 Premium    J            3897.
# … with 25 more rows
```